# What is the time complexity of Javascript Array.reduce() and Array.find()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to return an array of indexes of values that add up to a given target. I am trying to solve it the fastest way I can!

Examples:

```js
sumOfTwo([1, 2, 4, 4], 8)   // => [2, 3]
sumOfTwo([1, 2, 3, 9], 8)   // => []
```

So first I tried a simple brute-force. (Time complexity: **O(n^2)** )

```js
function sumOfTwo(arr, target) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] === target) {
        return [i, j];
      }
    }
  }

  return [];
}
```

Then I tried: (Time complexity: sorting **O(n log n)** + for loop **O(n)**)

```js
function sumOfTwo(arr, target) {
  const sortedArr = arr.sort();
  let idxFromBack = arr.length - 1;

  for (let [idx, val] of sortedArr.entries()) {
    if (val + arr[idxFromBack] > target) {
      idxFromBack--;
    }

    if (val + arr[idxFromBack] === target) {
      return [idx, idxFromBack];
    }
  }

  return [];
}
```

Then I came with this solution that I don't even know the time complexity.

```js
function sumOfTwo(arr, target) {
  const complements = [];

  for (let [idx, val] of arr.entries()) {
    if (complements.reduce((acc, v) => (acc || v.value === val), false)) {
      return [complements.find(v => v.value === target - val).index, idx];
    }

    complements.push({index: idx, value: target - val});
  }

  return [];
}
```

I know that I am using a for-loop but I don't know the complexity of the build-in high order functions `.reduce()` and `.find()`. I tried a couple of searches but I couldn't find anything.

If anyone can help me would be great! Please include Big-O notation if possible.

**Repl.it**: https://repl.it/@abranhe/sumOfTwo

---

Please also include the time complexity of the last solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The *minimum* time complexity of `.reduce` is `O(n)`, because it must iterate through all elements once (assuming an error isn't thrown), but it *can* be unbounded (since you can write any code you want inside the callback).

For your

```
  // Loop, O(n), n = length of arr:
  for (let [idx, val] of arr.entries()) {
    // .reduce, O(n), n = length of complements:
    if (complements.reduce((acc, v) => (acc || v.value === val), false)) {
      // If test succeeds, .find, O(n), n = length of complements:
      return [complements.find(v => v.value === target - val).index, idx];
    }

    complements.push({index: idx, value: target - val});
  }
```

the time complexity is, worst case, `O(n^2)`. The `reduce` runs in `O(n)` time, and you run a `reduce` for every entry in `arr`, making it `O(n^2)`.

(The `.find` is also an `O(n)` operation, but `O(n)` + `O(n)` = `O(n)`)

Your code that sorts the array beforehand has the right idea for decreasing complexity, but it has a couple flaws.

- First, you should sort *numerically* (`(a, b) => a - b)`); `.sort()` with no arguments will sort lexiographically (eg, `[1, 11, 2]` is not desirable).
- Second, just decrementing `idxFromBack` isn't enough: for example, `sumOfTwo([1, 3, 8, 9, 9], 9)` will not see that 1 and 8 are a match. Perhaps the best strategy here would be to oscillate with `while` instead: from a `idxFromBack`, iterate backwards until a match is found or the sum is too small, *and also* iterate forwards until a match is found or the sum is too large.

You can also improve the performance of this code by sorting not with `.sort((a, b) => a - b)`, which has complexity of `O(n log n)`, but with radix sort or counting sort instead (both of which have complexity of `O(n + k)`, where `k` is a constant). The optimal algorithm will depend on the general shape and variance of the input.

An even better, altogether different `O(n)` strategy would be to use a Map or object. When iterating over the array, put the value which *would result* in a match for the current item into a key of the object (where the value is the current index), and just look to see if the current value being iterated over exists in the object initially:

```js
const sumOfTwo = (arr, target) => {
  const obj = {};
  for (const [i, num] of arr.entries()) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(String(num))) {
      return [obj[num], i];
    }
    const matchForThis = target - num;
    obj[matchForThis] = i;
  }
  return [];
};

console.log(
  sumOfTwo([1, 2, 4, 4], 8),   // => [2, 3]
  sumOfTwo([1, 2, 8, 9], 9),  // 1 + 8 = 9; [0, 2]
  sumOfTwo([1, 2, 3, 9], 8)   // => []
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a supplementary answer, here is the algorithm of the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method [in the language spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find):

> When the find method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
> 2. Let len be ? LengthOfArrayLike(O).
> 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. Let k be 0.
> 5. Repeat, while k < len,
>
>    a. Let Pk be ! ToString((k)).
>
>    b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
>
>    c. Let testResult be ! ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, thisArg, « kValue, (k), O »)).
>
>    d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
>
>    e. Set k to k + 1.
> 6. Return undefined.

Note the **"repeat, while k < len"** in step 5. Since time complexity in general measures the *worst case* scenario (aka the upper bound), we can assume that the searched element is not present in the collection.

The number of iterations made during step 5 then is equal to `len` which directly depends on the *number of elements* in the collection. And what time complexity has a direct correlation to the number of elements? Exactly, the **linear O(n)**.

For a visual-ish demonstration, run the following snippet. Apart from some stray dots, the improvized graph should show a linear progression (takes a little while to display in Stack snippets, but you can watch it live in the devtools console):

```js
const iter = 1e7;
const incr = 2e5;

const test = new Array(iter).fill(0);
const steps = Math.ceil(iter / incr);

for (let i = 0; i < steps; i += 1) {
  const sub = test.slice(0, i * incr + incr);
    
  const s = Date.now();
  
  const find = sub.find((v) => v === 1);
  
  const e = Date.now();
  const d = e - s;
  
  console.log("\u200A".repeat(Math.floor(d/3))+"*");
}
```