# Getting an object from n object array if I have one of the keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very complex object that looks like this:

```
    [
       {type: "type", data: {a ton more stuff}}, 
       //with tons of these objects.
    ]
```

What I am wondering is if all 'type' keys are unique, could I get the object within the array with the given type or will I need to loop through the json array every time?? What I really need is the data, but I only know the type. This is a database schema that is not mine so unfortunately I cannot change the object.

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: "could I get the object within the array with the given type or will I need to loop through the json array every time??" yes, you will have to loop through the array. There are functions that can help you write this loop fairly quickly.

Comment: If you are searching like this frequently, then you should just loop over the array once and create an object or a Map that will allow you to do the lookup more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more efficient way, but you could use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const item = items.find(i => i.type === 'yourType');
```

You could also loop through once and create a `Map` if `type` is unique, using `type` as the key and the object as the value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: MEGA Dupe!!!!!!

Comment: I'm assuming this is just an O(n) function to find this item similar to looping?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670033/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-javascript-array-reduce-and-array-find

Answer (score -3):

Short answer is yes. Since it is an array of objects you need to loop through it. What you need is

```
const newArr = oldArr.filter(obj => (obj.type && obj.type === 'myType' && obj.data) ? obj.data : false));
```

Comment: I don't understand why my answer gets downvotes. all Array functions like map, find, filter and others just loop though the array. Downvote an answer without any comment is also a bad practice.