# using reduce inside a for loop make the code O(n) complexity or higher like O(n^2) or another kind?

Tags: javascript, performance

For an interview, they ask me to do some exercises and the 3rd one was the following:

We have an unknown quantity of elements in a vector/array v1 with random integer numbers.

- Made a v2 vector/array with the same length of v1 in that the v2[k] is the product of all the elements of v1 except v1[k]
- try to do it without the division operator and with complexity O(n).

And I do the following code:

```
const v1 = [4, 2, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7]; //it's just an example array
const l = v1.length;
let v2 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  let segment = v1.splice(0, 1); // save the number of the position in array that it'll exclude de product
  let product = v1.reduce((total, number) => { return total * number; }, 1);
  v2.push(product); // add the result to the v2 array at the position of the number of v1 array
  v1.push(segment); // is necesary to add again the segment of the v1 array to keep the original length
}

console.log('v2', v2);

/* Results Reference
product of all array    42674688    
product - position 00   10668672    
product - position 01   21337344    
product - position 02   6096384 
product - position 03   5334336 
product - position 04   7112448 
product - position 05   6096384 
product - position 06   4741632 
product - position 07   14224896    
product - position 08   21337344    
product - position 09   7112448 
product - position 10   6096384  
*/
```

My question is:

- Is my code an O(n) complexity? or is O(n^2)? or another kind of complexity?

thanks

Comment: Why you removed the `segment` then pushed it again? Did you think about `filter` ?

Comment: O(n) is tricky without using divide, O(n^2) is easy just use filter.. your push and reduce is adding more complexity.

Comment: the goal is to make an O(n) complexity script, so if I use `filter` it could gain complexity ap to n^2

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not O(n) because for each element of array `v1`, you run the `.reduce()` function that runs through the whole array, so it's O(n^2).

You can do it by calculating the total product, then iterating **once** through the `v1` array and pushing the `total / current` to the `v2` array. That way you will have the desired result with O(n) complexity.

```js
const v1 = [4, 2, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7];
const v2 = [];

const productTotal = v1.reduce((res, curr) => res * curr);

v1.forEach((el) => v2.push(productTotal/el));

console.log(v2);
```

So in total you iterate **twice** through the `v1` array - once to calculate `productTotal` and once to calculate `v2`, so in fact, that's a O(2n) complexity, but we can ignore the `2` because it's still O(n).

To achieve it without division you could use a trick, and instead of using division directly, you could use multiplication and the power of `-1` (don't know if that counts):

```js
const v1 = [4, 2, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7];
const v2 = [];

const productTotal = v1.reduce((res, curr) => res * curr);

v1.forEach((el) => v2.push(productTotal*Math.pow(el, -1)));

console.log(v2);
```

Comment: no, the division it's not allowed. I mean, take a total product and then divided by the v2[k] number it's not allowed. so, that's it's not the solution, even using the power of -1 it's the same as using the division. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62848580/8581025) by [@Sebastian Kaczmarek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7080548/sebastian-kaczmarek), the time complexity of your code is O(n^2) since [the time complexity of `.reduce` is O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670080/8581025) and `.reduce` is in the `for` loop which runs through the whole array.

One possible solution of which time complexity is O(n) and does not use division operator is the following:

```js
const v1 = [4, 2, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7];
const length = v1.length;

const v2 = new Array(length);

const listOfAccFromStart = new Array(length);
const listOfAccFromEnd = new Array(length);

let accFromStart = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  accFromStart *= v1[i];
  listOfAccFromStart[i] = accFromStart;
}

let accFromEnd = 1;
for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  accFromEnd *= v1[i];
  listOfAccFromEnd[i] = accFromEnd;
}

v2[0] = listOfAccFromEnd[1];
v2[length - 1] = listOfAccFromStart[length - 2];
for (let i = 1; i < length - 1; i++) {
  v2[i] = listOfAccFromStart[i - 1] * listOfAccFromEnd[i + 1];
}

console.log('v2', v2);
```

It saves the accumulated product values from start to `listOfAccFromStart` and the accumulated product values from end to `listOfAccFromEnd`. And it uses the saved values to set `v2`. Its time complexity is O(n) and its space complexity is O(n).